# Graphing a dataframe line plot with a legend in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with a dataset that has grades and states and need to create line graphs by state showing what percent of each state's students fall into which bins.

My methodology (so far) is as follows:
First I import the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


records = [{'Name':'A', 'Grade':'.15','State':'NJ'},{'Name':'B', 'Grade':'.15','State':'NJ'},{'Name':'C', 'Grade':'.43','State':'CA'},{'Name':'D', 'Grade':'.75','State':'CA'},{'Name':'E', 'Grade':'.17','State':'NJ'},{'Name':'F', 'Grade':'.85','State':'HI'},{'Name':'G', 'Grade':'.89','State':'HI'},{'Name':'H', 'Grade':'.38','State':'CA'},{'Name':'I', 'Grade':'.98','State':'NJ'},{'Name':'J', 'Grade':'.49','State':'NJ'},{'Name':'K', 'Grade':'.17','State':'CA'},{'Name':'K', 'Grade':'.94','State':'HI'},{'Name':'M', 'Grade':'.33','State':'HI'},{'Name':'N', 'Grade':'.22','State':'NJ'},{'Name':'O', 'Grade':'.7','State':'NJ'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.Grade = df.Grade.astype(float)
```

Next I cut each grade into a bin

```
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['Grade'],[-np.inf,.05,.1,.15,.2,.25,.3,.35,.4,.45,.5,.55,.6,.65,.7,.75,.8,.85,.9,.95,1],labels=False)/10
```

Then I create a pivot table giving me the count of people by bin in each state

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['bin'],columns='State',values=['Name'],aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique,margins=True)
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```

Then I convert those n-counts into percentages and remove the margin rows

```
df3 = df2.div(df2.iloc[-1])
df3 = df3.iloc[:-1,:-1]
```

Now I want to create a line graph with multiple lines (one for each state) with the bin on the x axis and the percentage on the Y axis. df3.plot() will give me the chart I want but I would like to accomplish the same using matplotlib, because it offers me greater customization of the graph. However, running

```
plt.plot(df3)
```

gives me the lines I need but I can't get the legend the work properly. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best way, but I use the pandas plot function to draw df3, then get the legend and get the new label names. Please note that the processing of the legend string is limited to this data.

```
line = df3.plot(kind='line')
handles, labels = line.get_legend_handles_labels()
label = []
for l in labels:
    label.append(l[7:-1])

plt.legend(handles, label, loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: This mostly works but in my actual data the line
```
label.append(l[7:-1])
```
is giving me some issues. I removed the brackets and everything in between and that seemed to work. Could you elaborate please on what that was intended to do?

Comment: Since the data obtained from the label is a string of the form '(names, CA)', I am extracting a legend string which I want to use in the slice function. You will need to find a way to deal with this on your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
plt.plot(df3,label="label")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

For more information visit [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

And if it helps you to solve your issues then don't forget to mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately when I try that, my legend shows three lines that are all labeled "label".

Comment: You have to change `plt.plot(df3,label="label")` "label" to label name accordingly in all 3 label.